# Would this be a fit for us?

Tags: evaluating-civicrm, civivolunteer

We are a small nonprofit that conducts medical missions and are looking for software to help us organize our missions. Your software looks like it could help us, but I have a few questions before signing up for a demo based on our core needs:
1. Can volunteers fill out their own profile that they manage themselves? As in, they sign into a profile and answer questions themselves.
2. Can we edit all the questions asked of volunteers in their profiles?
3. Can we AND volunteers upload documents?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Nadine...

You've asked more than one question, but I'll try to hit them all

1) CiviCRM lets you create public forms (profiles) that users can use to manage information in their contact record, such as email addresses, phone numbers and addresses. Depending on the CMS platform you're using, there are some other ways to allow for self-service updating of information, for example, on Drupal, there's a module called Webform that has excellent CiviCRM integration.

2) The profiles are completely configurable with all the core (built-in) CiviCRM fields and can include custom fields that you've set up in the database.

3) CiviCRM and all the supported CMSes allow for file uploads. CiviCRM lets you store attached files to contact records and activity records and can be configured for other record types, too.

You don't mention if you're going to be managing volunteers with CiviCRM. There's a video with some information about the CiviVolunteer extension on YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hkAlLYBc2Q

Answer (score 2):

You can use a demo for free here: https://civicrm.org/demo

1. It's not really designed for users to log in and answer questions, however, they can log in through your CMS/content management system (Drupal, Wordpress or Joomla driven website) and be given access to update their contact and other information.
2. What you are describing here, editing and posing questions, etc, is something you would do through your website, which could then store the information in CiviCRM
3. Access controls are handled through your website also. Anyone that has access to the CiviCRM would be able to upload documents.

Overall, CiviCRM is designed mostly to manage outreach to and contributions from donors as well as managing memberships, etc. I am not sure if this would be the best fit for what you are trying to do but it could definitely be adapted for your purpose as long as you understand that a lot of that is handled through your content management system first. Also, I wanted to make sure that you understand that you can't "sign up for a demo". It is free, open-source software that you can download and install to your website.

Update: I just found out about CiviSurvey, which might be really beneficial for you. Check it out here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/survey/what-is-civisurvey/

Answer (score 2):

I just want to make a suggestion : of course, CiviCRM will do all what you want.

But it must be installed upon a CMS : WordPress, Drupal, or Joomla.

From my own experience (I am not a programmer), I strongly recommend Drupal :

- easy to implement (like WordPress),
- easy to learn if you don't know it (like WordPress, but a different approach),
- very flexible in terms of permissions (more than WordPress),
- last, but not least : You can use WebForm and CiviCRM WebForm Integration Modules, which will make it very easy to do all what you ask for.